# using cURL -f on Windows

Tags: windows, curl

I made a bash script on Linux which looks like this:

```
if curl --fail (some other curl commands); then
        echo "Success"
else
        echo "Failed!"
fi;
```

and it works perfectly. However when I try the similar thing on Windows it doesn't work. I looked up how if then else works on windows and I tried:

```
if curl -f (some other commands) echo SUCCESS else echo FAIL
```

but it says "-f was unexpected"

my curl command works perfectly on windows without the if else statement.
So how do I check if curl failed or not on Windows?

**UPDATE:**

I solved it like this:

```
>nul curl -f (my other curl commands) && (
    echo SUCCESS
) || (
    echo FAIL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked!!

```
>nul curl -f (my other curl commands) && (
    echo SUCCESS
) || (
    echo FAIL
)
```

Hopefully this will help others as well